# tinyMce function to determine if popup is already open

Tags: tinymce

With tinyMce, I've got onclick code to open a plugin using this:
ed.windowManager.open(...)

Right now, it will open a 2nd, 3rd, etc. instance of this plugin window each time I click the target.

Instead, I want the onclick code to ignore the click if the window is already open. How can I detect the open window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I'm going with:

I seem to have confirmed:

-- that windowManager.open() does not return a reference to the window the same way that window.open() does

-- windowManager does not have a built-in way to limit the number of instances that can be opened.

But it does have a way to add an onClose function to the plugin window:
ed.windowManager.onClose.add(function() {alert('Closing!');});

So I'll be using a variable in the onClick code to keep track of whether the popup window has been opened and closed. The onClose function will mark that variable as closed